# How to retrieve data from the database when an option in a select tag in the jsp is selected

Tags: javascript, java, postgresql, jsp, jdbc

I want to be able to choose a program code from the drop down list in the jsp and without submitting get the corresponding program description from the database and display it in a textbox on the webpage. If anyone could let me know how to go about this, or what I need to look into that would be great, thanks.

```
<tr>
  <td><strong>Program Code</strong></td>
  <td>
    <select name="ProgramCode">
      <option value="-1" selected>[choose your program]</option>
      <option value="1">CPA</option>
      <option value="2">HSH</option>
      <option value="3">CP</option>
      <option value="4">RPN</option>
      <option value="5">CSTC</option>
      <option value="6">CFND</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Program Description</strong></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ProgramDescription" value="<%/*= programDescription */%>" size=20></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: "want to" is a rude way of letting us know we have to work for free for you. Please show effort with what you tried and motivate us by doing the required edit from which it shows effort...

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be rude, nor do I expect people to work for me, I would actually like some ideas on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use and onchange eventhandler. Set an program ID:

```
<select name="ProgramCode", ID="ProgramCode">
```

Then you need selection from the menu.

```
<input type="text" name="ProgramDescription" id="<%/*= programDescription */%>" size=20>
```

And integrate the below eventhandler:

```
var select = document.getElementById('ProgramCode');
var input  = document.getElementById('<%/*= programDescription */%>');

select.onchange = function() {
    input.value = select.value;
}
```

> Note: check if I have added a working ID for you (based on your value tag).

Comment: This was a big help thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.